# How to collect array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, selection

How to collect array of objects in javascript, example i have this array in this case :

```
var abc = [{"name": "udin", "checked": true}, {"name": "kabayan": "checked": true}, {"name": "hebring"}];
```

how to get result like this :

```
abc = [{"name": "udin", "checked": true}, {"name": "kabayan": "checked": true}];
```

i'm just want to showing only element with "checked" == true

Comment: depends where you need it. Very simple to filter a view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099029/how-to-filter-a-javascript-object-array-with-variable-parameters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use js native [*array filter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function like bellow

```
abc = abc.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.checked;
});
console.log(abc);
```

It will give you expected output.