# Filtering an array of objects based on their ID attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filter, itunes

Using iTunes' Search API I'm looking to grab a collection of songs from an album based on a specific criteria. I managed to get half of this done with the help of this this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17099280/3046413). The only problem is that there are times where an album can either be clean or explicit, which ultimately outputs duplicate songs.

I thought that the best solution in this case would be to grab the **first available** (and sometimes only) collection of songs based on their `collectionId`. Unfortunately this value isn't known offhand like the ones I pass in my `filter()` function.

How can I cleanly select just one group leveraging the code below:

```js
$(function() {
  iTunesSearch("Beauty Behind the Madness", "The Weeknd");

  function iTunesSearch(album, artist, callback) {
    var results;

    $.getJSON("http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + album + "&entity=song&callback=?", function(data) {
      results = data["results"];
      console.log( filter(results, { collectionName: album, artistName: artist }) );
    });
  }

  function filter(arr, criteria) {
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
      return Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
        return obj[c] == criteria[c];
      });
    });
  }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filter function does what you asked, i.e. it grabs the first collection of tracks

```
function filter(arr, criteria) {
    var tracks = arr.filter(function(track) {
        return Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
            return track[c] == criteria[c];
        });
    });
    if (!tracks.length) {
        return [];
    }
    return tracks.filter(function(track) {
        return track.collectionId == tracks[0].collectionId;
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is an optimization to avoid having two filter passes, but it makes it a bit harder to read:

```
function filter(arr, criteria) {
    var firstCollectionId = null;
    return arr.filter(function(track) {
        var isMatch = Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
            return track[c] == criteria[c];
        });
        if (isMatch) {
            if (firstCollectionId === null) {
                firstCollectionId = track.collectionId;
                return true;
            }
            return track.collectionId === firstCollectionId;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you think with this solution, `try/catch` would be helpful in regards to how you check whether the filtered tracks are empty? I was pondering a solution similar to what you have but couldn't come to a reasonable conclusion.

Comment: The `if(!tracks.length){return [];}` will return an empty array if there are no matching tracks.  I don't think a try/catch is necessary.

Comment: I see. One additional question. How come you decided to not wrap the return value inside an `else` block for the conditional? I'm referring to the second instance where the `filter()` method is called.

Comment: Personal style.  I prefer not to have else blocks if I can avoid it as another indent and more curly braces are more difficult for the human eye to parse

Comment: Great. Thanks so much for your help. For your second solution though I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Apologies I fixed that I should have put `arr` instead of `tracks`

Comment: On second thoughts that simplification/optimization is buggy

Comment: If the first track did not match your criteria then it would return an empty array

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks again.

Comment: I've added an optimization that is bug free

Comment: Thanks. I agree the first is a little more readable but always great to see the two alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to solve it :)

```js
$(function() {
  iTunesSearch("Beauty Behind the Madness", "The Weeknd");

  function iTunesSearch(album, artist, callback) {
    var results;

    $.getJSON("http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + album + "&entity=song&callback=?", function(data) {
      results = data["results"];
      console.log( filter(results, { collectionName: album, artistName: artist }, 'collectionId') );
    });
  }

  function filter(arr, criteria, key) {
    var keys = [];
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
      var keyVal = obj[key];
      var result = Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
        return obj[c] == criteria[c];
      }) && !keys.includes(keyVal);
      if(keyVal) keys.push(keyVal);
      return result;
    });
  }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand what it is you need... to have an array of unique songs from a particular album. If this is correct, here's a solution:

```
$(function() {

    iTunesSearch("Beauty+Behind+the+Madness", "The+Weeknd");

    function iTunesSearch(album, artist, callback) {
        var results,
            tracks = [];

        $.getJSON("http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + album + "&media=music&entity=song&callback=?", function(data) {
            data.results.map(function (album) {
                if (tracks.indexOf(album.trackName) === -1) {
                    tracks.push(album.trackName);
                }
            });
            console.log(tracks);
        });
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4vj05v7c/

I opted to populate the array with only track names so it would be easier to see that duplicates were not included.